# MS-Word-VBA UserForm - How to run a macro from a command button to a specific location inside the document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform, commandbutton

I can't figure out how to run a macro at a specific spot inside the Word document when a user presses the command button on the UserForm.  Currently when the command button is pressed the macro runs at the beginning of the document.  I tried finding a bookmark and running the macro there, but it still only initiates at the beginning of the document or wherever the last place the mouse clicked on the Word document.  Inside the document I have field codes around a checkbox, so when the checkbox is clicked "Yes" the macro runs and lines out a few sentences.

Original Checkbox in pic

[image]

This is what it is suppose to look like when the macro runs

[image]

Now the Macro works fine when the user clicks the checkbox on the document.  The code works inside the userform when the command button is clicked, but it runs the macro at the beginning of the document or wherever the mouse clicked last, instead of at the location of the checkmark.  Basically what I can't figure out is how to have the code click near the checkbox and then run the macro.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @StefanCrain The OP isn't able to do that - not enough reputation on the site.

Comment: Mike, you must include the macro code in your question, as well. You can use the [edit] link under your question. Without seeing the code we can't tell you what might be wrong with it. You also need to tell us exactly what part of the document the macro should target. Also, it look as you're using form fields? So is the document *protected* as a form? Is the entire document protected, or just part of it?

Comment: If it doesn't have any proprietary stuff in it, can you upload the Document in question?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally figure this out. I delayed asking the question on here for days trying to do research on my own.  But of course, hours after I post on here I figure it out.

All I needed was these 2 lines

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BookmarkName").Select
MacroName
```